# Uncaught DOMException (in promise) - Hijack specific GraphQL request in the serviceworker

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, service-worker, fetch-api

I try to hijack a specific GraphQL-Request via the service-worker to fake the response from data in my IndexedDB, but I get an error that the event already has been responded to. The fetching is working for cached files, if the fetched data is not in the cache it will use the network. If there is no network there will be an offline fallback. How can I orchestrate my Promises that I can also hijack requests to my GraphQL API and a specific Query (operationName), because it seems i messed up with async event.respondWith calls ?

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    if (event.request.url === __GRAPHQL_URL__) {
        event.request.clone().json().then(({operationName, variables}) => {
            switch (operationName) {
                case 'getOfflineFacilities':
                    //when a fetch is matching there will be the error
                    event.respondWith(serveOfflineFacilities());
            }
        });
    }else{

        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
                console.log("cache or network fallback");
                return response || fetch(event.request);
            }).catch(function () {
                console.log("offline fallback");
                return caches.match('/index.html');
            })
        );
    }
});
```

Error when there is a GraphQL Query that is hitting **__GRAPHQL_URL__** and my **operationName**

`sw.js:41 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'respondWith' on 'FetchEvent': The event has already been responded to.`

Comment: Is the only `fetch` event listener?

Comment: Notice that you never handle failures of the `event.request.clone().json()` promise

Comment: Yes it’s the only one

Comment: The event.respondWith in my switch case is out of reach. Do you know hoe to fix this that there will noch response earlier ?

Comment: The one in my code above. My problem is that everything in my switch case has already been responded to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sparsely documented, but you need to call the [`respondWith` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent/respondWith) *immediately* in the handler. If the event handler exits and `respondWith` had not been called, the request [will be handled](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#on-fetch-request-algorithm) so that the default response is served. [`respondWith` will check the `dispatch flag`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#fetch-event-respondwith) that is only set during the event handler call - when you only call it from a promise callback, you will get the "*The event has already been responded to*" exception.

So you need to change your code to pass the whole promise to `respondWith`:

```
if (event.request.url === __GRAPHQL_URL__) {
    event.respondWith(event.request.clone().json().then(({operationName, variables}) => {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        switch (operationName) {
            case 'getOfflineFacilities':
                return serveOfflineFacilities();
//              ^^^^^^
        }
    }));
//    ^
}
```